# Android View Animation: how does android:fromXDelta and android:toXDelta work?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying add an animation effect when I add a `PopupWindow` to my Activity.

The effect that I want to create is depicted in this picture:

[image]

As you can see the PopupWindow enters from the left, goes to **30**, then goes to **-10** and finallyy rests in the center position at **0**.

This is an example of what I unsuccessfully tried:

```
<translate
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="30%p" />

<translate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXDelta="30%p"
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:toXDelta="-10%p" />

<translate
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromXDelta="-10%p"
    android:startOffset="2300"
    android:toXDelta="10%p" />
```

But every combination I try leads to completely different results!!!

I am very perplexed by the meaning of `android:fromXDelta` and `android:toXDelta`,

please can anybody explain it to me?

(IMHO what is in the official documentation in really not clear).

You can try it here https://github.com/LisaAbate/test.git

Comment: use one translate animation in conjunction with a custom Interpolator

Comment: @pskink yes indeed, but why does this not work???

Comment: do you really need to know? ;-) as far i know AnimationSet really works well with different properties eg translate + rotate + alpha,  when you try to combine two translates weird things happen,  really weird, avoid that

Comment: @pskink yes I would love to, if possible :-) and I confirm: I have been experiencing incomprehensible things with this animation

Comment: i think the problem is here: http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.java line 385, t.compose(temp); where compose method is here http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/animation/Transformation.java#109 it composes two matrices by preconcating while in my opinion it should use postconcating

Comment: @pskink so this in your opinion is a bug?

Comment: who i am to judge? as i said: one translate + custom interpolator make the job